# Guice configuration error: No implementation was bound

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm trying to make DI with Guice work, doing (as it seems to me) exactly what's in [the manual](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations).

I can't explain the problem because I don't really understand it - everything seems very logical and should work.. but it doesn't. So, I can only attach the code and the stacktrace:

```
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new TestModule());
        //next line throws the exception
        JMeterComponent jMeterComponent = 
             injector.getInstance(JMeterComponent.class);
        ....
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to instantiate object of `JMeterComponent` class. It's constructor (as you'll see later) accepts 3 arguments: all of them should be also instantiated by IoC and injected.

And here's the `TestModule` with configuration of these 3 arguments:

```
public class TestModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Callable.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("JMeter"))
                  .to(JMeterTask.class);      
        bind(Processor.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("JMeter"))
                  .to(JMeterResultsProcessor.class);
        bind(Renderer.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("JMeter"))
                  .to(JMeterResultsWikiRenderer.class);
    }
}
```

Now, let's look at those concrete implementations - `JMeterTask`, `JMeterResultsProcessor` and `JMeterResultsWikiRenderer` (all of them have fake bodies for the simplicity):

```
public class JMeterTask implements Callable<JMeterRawResults> {

    public JMeterRawResults call() throws Exception {
        return new JMeterRawResults();
    }
}
```

```
public class JMeterResultsProcessor implements 
                   Processor<JMeterRawResults, JMeterResults> {

    public JMeterResults process(JMeterRawResults raw) {
        return new JMeterResults();
    }
}
```

```
public class JMeterResultsWikiRenderer implements Renderer<JMeterResults> {

    public Map<String, String> render(JMeterResults jMeterResults) {
        Map<String, String> results = Maps.newHashMap();
        ...
        return results;
    }
}
```

And now let's look at the `JMeterComponent` class, which instance's construction is the aim of the whole DI-related stuff here:

```
public class JMeterComponent extends AbstractComponent<String, String> {

    @Inject
    public JMeterComponent(@Named("JMeter") Callable<String> task, 
                           @Named("JMeter")Processor<String, String> processor, 
                           @Named("JMeter")Renderer<String> renderer) {
        super(task, processor, renderer);
    }
}
```

And here's the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for stat.domain.Processor<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=JMeter) was bound.
  while locating stat.domain.Processor<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=JMeter)
    for parameter 1 at stat.components.jmeter.JMeterComponent.<init>(JMeterComponent.java:18)
  while locating cstat.components.jmeter.JMeterComponent

2) No implementation for stat.domain.Renderer<java.lang.String> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=JMeter) was bound.
  while locating stat.domain.Renderer<java.lang.String> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=JMeter)
    for parameter 2 at stat.components.jmeter.JMeterComponent.<init>(JMeterComponent.java:18)
  while locating stat.components.jmeter.JMeterComponent

3) No implementation for java.util.concurrent.Callable<java.lang.String> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=JMeter) was bound.
  while locating java.util.concurrent.Callable<java.lang.String> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=JMeter)
    for parameter 0 at stat.components.jmeter.JMeterComponent.<init>(JMeterComponent.java:18)
  while locating stat.components.jmeter.JMeterComponent
```

Some additional facts:

1. I use guice-2.0 (with `featured`
   label)
2. There's no more any annotation from `com.google.inject` package in any other class in the code
3. Interfaces `Processor` and `Renderer` are placed in one module, and their `jmeter`-implementations (`JMeterResultsProcessor` and other) and `JMeterComponent` class are placed in another module.

That's pretty much everything there's to say about it.

Sorry for such a long post and thanks for your patience to read it to the end.

Any ideas on why did the errors occur and how to fix it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several problems I'm seeing here.

First, `Callable` and `Callable<String>` are different. If you want to inject a `Callable<String>` (or `Processor<String, String>`, etc.) in Guice, you have to bind something to `Callable<String>`, not `Callable`.

Second, you're binding `Callable` to `JMeterTask` which implements `Callable<JMeterRawResults>` but you're injecting `Callable<String>` in `JMeterComponent`'s constructor (same deal for `Processor` and `Renderer`). I'm going to assume that `JMeterComponent` should have `Callable<JMeterRawResults>` etc. injected.

Anyway, what you need to do is *generic* bindings using `TypeLiteral`:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Callable<JMeterRawResults>>(){})
    .annotatedWith(Names.named("JMeter"))
    .to(JMeterTask.class);
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Unfortunately, it looks not pretty well. Anyway, thanks very much.

Comment: Agreed that this looks ugly. I usually define the literals in instance variables in the modules, because they are somehow static. This makes the bind statement a lot nicer.

Comment: I don't really see the big deal. Once you get used to the `TypeLiteral` idiom in Guice, it looks perfectly natural there. I say don't fight the idiomatic way of doing things in Guice... but whatever you prefer.

Comment: When you use Guice, the module is where the ugly code is supposed to go, so you don't need ugly code in your business logic.